# How to filter by date/time in an MS Access report?

Tags: ms-access

I'm developing a couple of MS Access reports; one of them needs to know if a particular date/time field is empty, the other is the opposite.  I've tried the following in the Filter property in the Data tab of the Report property sheet:

```
IsNull( Assets.[Sales Date Seller Paid] )
```

When I look at the Report View, the date/time items are often null, but actual date values appear as well.

[image: Report showing invalid date/time data]

Am I on the right track?

Comment: I only use that if I have a report where I want the filter to change dynamically. Normally I would add any permanent filtering to the report's record source.

Comment: You could add a button at the top of your report that would toggle the filter to null or not null (option or checkbox, or...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsNull` in Access is a **function** that replaces null values with something else (specified as the second parameter in the function, but leaving this blank will return ?not sure - might depend on the data type of the first parameter). Anyway, what you really need is:

```
Assets.[Sales Date Seller Paid] Is Null
```

And yes, as @SunKnight0 says, it would possibly be better to include that in the underlying query.

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking of `Nz()`? `IsNull` should test whether an expression is null or not and returns a boolean. It does not do any replacing of values. I agree though, that `is null` is the correct way to go here.

Comment: Oops! SQL Server creeping in there. Thanks for the correction. In which case, why does `IsNull` not do the job?

Comment: It is a VBA expression for testing if variables are null (similar to `Is Nothing` for objects) It's not really an "Access" function in that the full function is `VBA.Information.IsNull()`, it's really a VBA thing. Because column being null is different than a variable being null it's just not the thing to use. As to *why* that is the case....I don't know.